# how to do hashing for 2 dimensional arrays of size N?

Tags: c++, hash

How to do hashing for 2 dimensional arrays of size upto 15 *15.The hash function must identify each arrangement uniquely. For example for a 4*4 matrix 
hash = 0;

```
hash = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        hash *= 13;
        hash += board[i][j];
        if (hash > 10000003)
            hash %= 10000003;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with parameterizing the 4?

Comment: By [Pigeon Hole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), it's not possible to get a unique hash for every single possible arrangement of the matrix. (Unless you have fewer possible arrangements than the # of different hash values.)